# How to make short film with WebGL

Tags: webgl

Is it possible to make a short film using WebGL? I see tons of examples on animating an object or trigger based animation but nothing like film. I am new to this field.

Comment: What do you mean by a "short film"?

Comment: Just like short 5 minutes youtube clip. Not a game where it is trigger based (such as onClick, etc).

Comment: You mean like show some video (avi clip) or like rendered with 3d?

Comment: I want to create a short 3D film, a short story rendered in 3D. So its not event driven, next scene will start one current scene (frame?) is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebGL is just a graphics library. You'll need an animation engine (or game engine that has animation built in) and you'll need an authoring program to make the animation.

You might try [babylon.js](http://www.babylonjs.com/)

Theoretically you could make an animation in Blender or 3DSMax or Maya, export to FBX and import through the converters included in the engine. I suspect it's not setup to handle whole 3D scenes as is though.

[Three.js](http://threejs.org/) might do it as well but I suspect it also doesn't handle full scenes directly out of the 3D program.

I suggest you start small. Make a simple animated scene using a few primitives and see if you can export it into one of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Inka3D, which is a Maya to WebGL exporter, has been used to create so-called demos which are close to short films. These are called "Azathioprine", "Radiotherapy" and "70s". You can simply use maya as usual only with some limitations and make your short film. See www.inka3d.com for links to the demos.